# How is JavaScript's Reduce assigning its value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mapreduce, reducers

**Problem:** I do not understand how `reduce` is assigning/reducing the customer name from the array. I need for someone to please explain precisely what is happening here.

**Detailed Description**

In episode 4 of *Fun Fun Function*'s functional programming series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DMolJ2FrNY), Mattias Petter Johansson walks through an example of loading in a simple data set for customers and their orders and transforming that data into hierarchical objects via the `reduce` function.

Here is the sample tab-delimited data set--which I named locally as `data.txt`.

```
mark johannson  waffle iron 80  2
mark johannson  blender 200 1
mark johannson  knife   10  4
Nikita Smith    waffle iron 80  1
Nikita Smith    knife   10  2
Nikita Smith    pot 20  3
```

Here is the JavaScript file which loads and processes the data set--which I named locally as `reduce.js`.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var output = fs
    .readFileSync("data.txt", "utf-8")
    .trim()
    // NOTE: On Windows, I needed to use \r\n. You may only need \r or \n.
    .split("\r\n")
    .map(line => line.split("\t"))
    .reduce((customers, line) => {
        customers[line[0]] = customers[line[0]] || [];
        customers[line[0]].push({
            name: line[1],
            price: line[2],
            quantity: line[3]
        });
        return customers;
    }, {});

console.log("output", JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Finally, here is the simple command which I use to execute this js file via `NodeJS`.

```
node reduce.js
```

*(Alternately, if you would like to see all of the code and data together in one place, I have included a jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/anthonygatlin/27vpoa13/)*

The output from code execution looks something like

```
{
  "mark johannson": [
    {
      "name": "waffle iron",
      "price": "80",
      "quantity": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "blender",
      "price": "200",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "knife",
      "price": "10",
      "quantity": "4"
    }
  ],
  "Nikita Smith": [
    {
      "name": "waffle iron",
      "price": "80",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "knife",
      "price": "10",
      "quantity": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "pot",
      "price": "20",
      "quantity": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's quickly walk through what is happening in the code.

- The `.readFileSync("data.txt", "utf-8")` reads in the file using `utf-8` encoding. (Otherwise, the text is unintelligible.)

Before `utf-8` conversion...

```
<Buffer 6d 61 72 6b 20 6a 6f 68 61 6e 6e 73 6f 6e 09 77 61 66 66 6c 65 20 69 72 6f 6e 09 38 30 09 32 0d 0a 6d 61 72 6b 20 6a 6f 68 61 6e 6e 73 6f 6e
09 62 6c ... >
```

After `utf-8` conversion...

```
mark johannson  waffle iron     80      2
mark johannson  blender 200     1
mark johannson  knife   10      4
Nikita Smith    waffle iron     80      1
Nikita Smith    knife   10      2
Nikita Smith    pot     20      3
```

- The `.trim()` function removes any newline character at the end of the file.
- The `.split("\r\n")` and `.map(line => line.split("\t"))` functions convert the incoming file text into an array of arrays.

After `.split("\r\n")`

```
[ 'mark johannson\twaffle iron\t80\t2',
  'mark johannson\tblender\t200\t1',
  'mark johannson\tknife\t10\t4',
  'Nikita Smith\twaffle iron\t80\t1',
  'Nikita Smith\tknife\t10\t2',
  'Nikita Smith\tpot\t20\t3' ]
```

After `.map(line => line.split("\t"))`

```
[ [ 'mark johannson', 'waffle iron', '80', '2' ],
  [ 'mark johannson', 'blender', '200', '1' ],
  [ 'mark johannson', 'knife', '10', '4' ],
  [ 'Nikita Smith', 'waffle iron', '80', '1' ],
  [ 'Nikita Smith', 'knife', '10', '2' ],
  [ 'Nikita Smith', 'pot', '20', '3' ] ]
```

It is important to point out there are exactly four elements in each row of the array. These correspond to `customer name` [index 0], `item name` [index 1], `price` [index 2], and `quantity` [index 3].

- The `.reduce...` function transforms the array into JavaScript objects.

  ```
  .reduce((customers, line) => {
      customers[line[0]] = customers[line[0]] || [];
      customers[line[0]].push({
          name: line[1],
          price: line[2],
          quantity: line[3]
      });
      return customers;
  }, {});
  ```

Reduce accepts three parameters here (although we have not provided two other optional parameters.) The provided parameters are: 1) the current value of reduce's accumulator denoted by our variable `customers`, the current row in the array represented by our variable `line`, and the starting value upon which reduce will build--provided by the empty object literal `{}`.

The values of our line variable are

1. `line[0]` = customer name
2. `line[1]` = product name
3. `line[2]` = price
4. `line[3]` = quantity

Within the reduce function, three things are occurring.

1. From, `customers[line[0]] = customers[line[0]] || [];`, we are (somehow magically) extracting out each customer. This keeps the current customer if one exists or sets the customer to an empty array if there is no customer.

   **QUESTION: Even if we have the line set to `customers[line[0]] = []`, then a `customer name` still gets returned. *How in the world is this possible?* If we set the `customer` to an empty array, how is `reduce` returning a value for `customer`? In `customers[line[0]] = []`, we aren't pushing anything onto an array.**

   I am absolutely confused how the customer gets set here and returned if we set customers[line[0]] to an empty array and never push the value of line[0] onto customer.
2. The data for an item's `name`, `price`, and `quantity` are pushed into an array attached to the customer.

   ```
       customers[line[0]].push({
           name: line[1],
           price: line[2],
           quantity: line[3]
   ```
3. The `customer` object is returned and feeds the next iteration of `reduce`. When no more lines of the array are available for processing, the `customer` array is returned as the final result.

Comment: Kudos on the very thorough question

Comment: You'll get quicker answers if you limit your question to the part that you don't understand, and keep extra noise to a minimum. Verbosity doesn't always beget clarity. This question could be asked with a *minimal*, to-the-point example. This allows helpers to not have to spend extra time reading text that isn't a material part of the confusion.

Comment: "*Reduce accepts three parameters here*" - no. `reduce` accepts two parameters: a callback function and the the initial value for the accumulator. The callback function is called with the current accumulator value as the first argument and an array element as the second argument, and returns the next accumulator value.

Comment: @Bergi, Thank you for the comment. However, reduce actually accepts a total of five parameters--with four of them being passed directly as parameters (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, and array) and the fifth parameter, the initialValue being passed at the end of the function definition. CurrentIndex and array parameters are optional and are infrequently used. The initialValue is also optional but is generally recommended. Please see the Mozilla Developer Network documentation for more info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin No. Reduce is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that accepts two parameters (one of them being optional). The first of those needs to be a function that will be called with four arguments (and may declare/use any number of them). You are confused by the formatting of the MDN page - those four you named are the arguments of the `callback` parameter.

Comment: @Bergi, You are absolutely correct. I was mistaken. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line[0] is the customer's name. That means that this:

```
customers[line[0]] = customers[line[0]] || []
```

is equal to this:

```
const customerName = line[0];
customers[customerName] = customers[customerName] || [];
```

what it does is it makes sure that before trying to push objects into a customer list, a list actually exists. Let's assign and see what happens:

```
customers['mark johnson'] = customers['mark johnson'] || [];
```

So the customers object is assigned an empty list to property 'mark johnson' when nothing is there, or the list that's currently there.

so it's equivalent to this:

```
const customerName = line[0];
if (!customers[customerName]) {
    customers[customerName] = [];
}
```

The code after that is basically destructing the 'line' list, and mapping it to properties on an object, that is pushed to the above list. So it's equivalent to this:

```
.reduce((customers, line) => {
    const customerName = line[0];
    if (!customers[customerName]) {
        customers[customerName] = [];
    }
    const price = line[2];
    const quantity = line[3];
    const currentLine = {
        name: customerName,
        price: price,
        quantity: quantity
    };

    customers[customerName].push(currentLine);
    return customers;
}, {});
```

But obviously the previous code is better :)
It can be a bit more clear if using Destructuring:

```
.reduce((customers, [name, price, quantity]) => {
    customers[name] = customers[name] || [];
    customers[name].push({name, price, quantity});
    return customers;
}, {});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: This is very helpful @Aviv. Thank you so much!